# Getting Transform Exception while building the project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I am getting the following error when I try to run my app:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

Here is my app level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.galleri5.android'
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "0.8.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.8.0+'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp:0.8.0+'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.liuguangqiang.swipeback:library:1.0.2@aar'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

And here is my project level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Why is this error coming and how to resolve it?

Comment: Actually the OP's error is different from the one marked as duplicate.The error from the question shows it exits with error value 3!

Comment: Clean priject -> restart android studio -> clean project :)

Answer (score 8):

Enable multidex, it solve the problem for me.

```
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

For any query, feel free to raise it.

Comment: I already have multiDexEnabled true. Anyways, I cleaned the project and then ran it, it is working now.

Comment: i have same problem i apply following code to solve issue 

javaMaxHeapSize "4g"