# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:..non-zero exit value 3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After **Clean Project** -> **Rebuild Project** my android project I am getting below error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

**Gradle :**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapplicationname.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
    //facebook sdk
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.3'

    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.12.4'
    //facebook sdk
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'

}
```

I already refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515018/getting-transform-exception-while-building-the-project) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369163/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-while-implement) , But I can't got my solution.What I need to do to resolve it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just update my **gradle** file like below.This work like charm!!

I added below code in my gradle:

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        preDexLibraries = false //delete the already predexed libraries
    }
```

My updated **Gradle**:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapplicationname.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
  //====================Add below two line=============
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        preDexLibraries = false //delete the already predexed libraries
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
    //facebook sdk
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.3'

    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.12.4'
    //facebook sdk
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'

}
```

Comment: Save my life, but care to explain what the f*ck is that problem and why the code resolves it ? THANKS

Answer (score 2):

The possible solution could be to specify play services you're using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

for example like:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
```

It will decrease total methods amount.